# UITableView cannot reload the data from CustomCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, plist, reloaddata

I have an UITableView with CustomCells. It is a favorites list and there is star images in every CustomCell. So if I click lighted stars again they have to be disappeared and removed from properties list called fav.plist.

But when I click the lighted stars they don't disappear. I can't reload the datas in Favorite list from CustomCell.m . TO disappear the datas that I clicked the star , I have to go that View again. It is the only way to reload the data.

How can I make it reload the datas after click the star with stay at the same view?

Here is a part of my CustomCell.m code  where the favorite list is (UITableView for the list is favView, the plist is fav.plist):

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *favList; 

  //First I find the item from plist which one will be removed from fav.plist.
    NSString *path_fav = [[self documentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fav.plist"];
    self.favList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path_fav]; 
    for (NSInteger i=0; i<[self.favList count];i++) {
        d = [self.favList objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *code=[d objectForKey:@"CODE"];
        NSComparisonResult res=[code compare:self.cityLabel.text];
        if(res==NSOrderedSame){
            //removing from the fav.plist
            [self.favList removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            //Here I try to reload the data for the UITableView called favView
            //In Favorite.m is my UITableView called favView
            NSString *path = [[self documentsDirectory]
                              stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fav.plist"];                
            [self.favList writeToFile:path atomically:TRUE];
            Favorite *favController =[[Favorite alloc]init];
            [favController.favView reloadData];
            [favController.favView reloadInputViews];

        }
    }
```

Here is one part of my Favorite.m code:

```
-  (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *cellID = @"cellid";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID ];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = (CustomCell*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                              loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil]
                             lastObject];
    }

    NSDictionary *d = [self.favList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = [d objectForKey:@"NAME"];
    cell.cityLabel.text = [d objectForKey:@"CODE"];
    cell.index= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
    cell.indexPath = indexPath;

    NSString *starName;
    if([[d objectForKey:@"FAV"] intValue]==0){
        starName=@"star.png";
    }else{
        starName=@"starb.png";
    }

    [cell.self.starbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:starName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    if((indexPath.row % 2) ==0)
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:241/256.0 green:237/256.0 blue:237/256.0 alpha:1.0];
    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(320/2, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize nameSize = [cell.nameLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    if(nameSize.height>=72)
        nameSize.height=63;
    else
        nameSize.height=38;
    cell.nameLabel.frame =CGRectMake(80, 0, 213, nameSize.height);
    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u implement the Method

(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

If yes then in this perform deletion and reload in this method.

Comment: But I can only do the deletion in CustomCell. And I dont select the Cell I only push a button in CustomCell.

Comment: are you Calling the method [YourTableView reloadData]; in CustomCell , it will reload the data.

Comment: try with singleton object , instead of allocating each time Favorite *favController =[[Favorite alloc]init];
Take shared controller then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reload a cell from itself. As far as I got your Question,you need to implement Delegate protocol for your cell. As star is pressed, call method for your button in customcell.m, which removes star from plist file and do other stuff. Then call method on delegate(your view) to reload that cell. If you don't understand I can provide u example.